# XSLT expression for grouping nodes with same value (when value is unknown)?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

XML File:

```
<books>
    <scifi key=...>
       <author>Don Larson</author>
       <title>The Edge</title>
       <year>...</year>
    </scifi>
    <scifi key=...>
       <author>Don Larson</author>
       <author>James Kiddleton</author>
       <author>Danny Wobers</author>
       <title>Incognitum</title>
       <year>1987</year>
    </scifi>
    <scifi key=...>
       <author>....</author>
       <author>....</author>
       <title>...</title>
       <year>...</year>
    </scifi>
    etc......................
</books>
```

XSL File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <center><h3>Results :</h3>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Authors</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select=..............
      ...............
      ........
```

How do I present the information in my XML file by author? Don Larson appears in two titles so I want to get a table where one cell has the name Dan Larson and the cell next to it has the two titles related to Dan Larson.. etc..(btw: it's possible that one author only has one title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="author" match="scifi" use="author"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="scifi[generate-id() = generate-id(key('author', author))]"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="scifi">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
      </td>

      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('author', author)">
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <br/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Don Larson</td>
    <td>The Edge<br />Incognitum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there  an XSLT expression for comparing values of different nodes? Something like: `for-each select="book/scifi/" ` and inside of that something like: `if value-of select="author" is the same` in any of those nodes then group value-of title of each of those nodes under same author? (bypassing the need for keys and ids, since I'm not familiar with more complicated expressions like the ones you used..) thanks once again for your help!

Comment: You can compare values in different nodes, but if you want to group then Kirill solution is the way to go, there are no 'shorcuts'